# Installation of pkgconfig on Windows

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

I have successfully installed and loaded `readxl` package. When I am trying to use the function `readxl::read_xlsx()`, it throws and error that R cannot find `pkgconfig`.

I have tried to install this package, but it throws another error, which is presented below:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Maintenant Prêt!/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
pkgconfig  2.0.2  2.0.3             FALSE

installing the source package ‘pkgconfig’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pkgconfig_2.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6080 bytes
downloaded 6080 bytes

* installing *source* package 'pkgconfig' ...
** package 'pkgconfig' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Maintenant Prjt!/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-pkgconfig/00new/pkgconfig/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'pkgconfig'
* removing 'C:/Users/Maintenant Prêt!/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/pkgconfig'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgconfig’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have checked and there are no hidden `00LOCK` folders in packages folder, which can conflict with installation. My three suggestions are: (1) either there are no writing rights to this folder (which is wired since all packages are installed normally), (2) or a special symbol ê in the name of the parent folder creates problems.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Here are results of the `sessionInfo()` and `.libPaths()`:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.1 cellranger_1.1.0
 [5] R6_2.4.0         magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.4.2     rlang_0.4.0     
 [9] rstudioapi_0.10  tools_3.6.1      glue_1.3.1       compiler_3.6.1
```

and

```
[1] "C:/Users/Maintenant Prêt!/Documents/R/win-library/3.6"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library"
```

Comment: Do you have RTools installed?Is(well are they) it up to date? Have you tried installing with all dependencies set to `TRUE`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because having difficulties installing a package is a support issue. The poster should contact the authors. Stackoverflow is a programming site, for programming questions, not software installation support.

Comment: @NelsonGon Thanks a lot, it worked well.